# a:hover and css-class overlapping

Tags: html, css, html-lists, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make a side-menu in wordpress, which is going nicely, but for some reason the css is being a pain and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

The navigation looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="page_item page-item-8 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.consana.nl/diensten/">Diensten</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-32"><a href="http://www.consana.nl/diensten/dienst-1/">Dienst 1</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-33"><a href="http://www.consana.nl/diensten/dienst-2/">Dienst 2</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-36"><a href="http://www.consana.nl/diensten/dienst-3/">Dienst 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

The css for this looks like this:

```
#left-side nav a:hover, #left-side nav .current_page_item{
   border-left:10px #b8d276 solid;
   border-right:none;
   padding-left:10px;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

Now when one of the items is "selected" (having the .current_page_item-tag) the hover is again applied, what shouldn't happen, it should just stay the same.

On the following page you can see it in action: http://www.consana.nl/en/diensten/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<li>` has default `border-left` and you are styling anchor elements.

```
#left-side nav li:hover, #left-side nav .current_page_item{
   border-left:10px #b8d276 solid;
   border-right:none;
   padding-left:10px;
   font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: thx! that totally fixed the problem, that's one thing i won't forget anymore :)